# Implementing threads with sockets in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

so i'm trying to implement a basic client-server calculator with threads. I was able to implement the communication between cliente-server with sockets but i'm at a loss when i try to add threads to the code. 
This is my first time using this forum so please sorry if i'm making a dumb question but i already searched for some answers and i can't find anything that helps :(
I can upload my whole code bit for now i think this will suffice:

Creating a thread in main:

```
  while(cliente_socket_fd  = accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&name_cliente,(socklen_t*)&cliente_name_len))
  {
      pthread_t thread;
      new_sock = malloc(1);
      *new_sock = cliente_socket_fd;
      if(i <= nThreads) // nThreads is the maximum of threads permitted
      {
          if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, connectionSocket, (void*)new_sock) < 0)
          {
              perror("Error");
              return 1;
          }    
          i++;
      }    
     }
```

Function that recives information from create thread:

```
 void *connectionSocket(void *sockR)
    {
        int sock = *(int*)sockR;
        int x;
        char buffer[1024];
        do{
           x = strlen(buffer) + 1;
           read(sock,buffer, x);

           readSocket(sock, buffer);
           }while(1 || strcmp(buffer,"end") != 0);

        close(sock);
        return 0;
    }
```

Server read socket function:

```
int readSocket(int sock, const char* buffer)
{
   //char buffer[1024];
   //char message[1024] ;
   int ssize;

   ssize = strlen(buffer);
   if(ssize == 0)
      return 0;
   char* message = (char*) malloc(ssize);


   //memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
   memset(message, 0, sizeof message);

   strcat(message, buffer);
...
   writeSocket(sock, message);
...
```

Function that writes in the socket:

```
void writeSocket(int sock, const char* mensagem)
{
   int ssize = strlen(message) + 1;

   write(sock, &ssize, sizeof(ssize));
   write(sock, message, ssize);
}
```

Again sorry if i'm being a noob or asking too much but any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: One thing: 'while(cliente_socket_fd  = accept());'  why would that expression be true?

Comment: Oh.. and 'new_sock = malloc(1);' - not big enough.

Comment: connectionSocket() does not free the parameter, (that you malloced to the wrong size). after it's done with it.

Comment: 'ssize = strlen(buffer);' C 'string' library call on an array of char that is not securely NUL terminated.

Comment: 'readSocket()' does not read the socket.

Comment: You need to go through all your code with a debugger.  You have too many serious bugs and too much missing/misleading code/data for us to help much.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i'm kind at a loss using threads but i will try to work on your suggestions. Thank you all for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in function: connectionSocket()

this line

```
x = strlen(buffer) + 1;
```

is garbage because `strlen()` stops when it finds a NUL byte.

However, the `buffer` has not been set to a known condition so there may or may not be a NUL byte in the buffer. I.E. undefined behavior.

---

the `accept()` function returns -1 when an error occurs, However the posted code will blindly continue into the body of the loop

Suggest writing that line similar to:

```
while( 1 )
{
    cliente_socket_fd  = accept(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&name_cliente, (socklen_t*)&cliente_name_len) );
    if( -1 == cliente_socket_fd )
    {
        perror( "accept failed" );
        break;  // exit loop
    }

    // implied else, accept successful
```

---

then, to be able to access those threads, later, this line:

```
if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, connectionSocket, (void*)new_sock) < 0)
```

should be setting a 'unique' 'thread' rather than the only 'thread'  Suggest:

```
pthread_t thread[ nThreads ] = {0};

if(pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, connectionSocket, (void*)new_sock) < 0)
```

---

then, a socket is (effectively) an integer, which, depending on the underlying hardware architecture is 4 or 8 bytes  So this line:

```
new_sock = malloc(1);
```

does not allocate enough bytes, it should be:

```
new_sock = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
if( !new_sock )
{ // then, malloc failed
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    break;  // exit loop
}

// implied else, malloc successful

*new_sock = cliente_socket_fd;
```

---

this line:

```
}while(1 || strcmp(buffer,"end") != 0);
```

will never exit the loop.  Suggest:

```
}while( strcmp(buffer,"end") != 0 );
```

---

this line:

```
read(sock,buffer, x);
```

will try to read some random number of bytes because the value in 'x' is not valid.  Suggest;

```
read(sock,buffer, sizeof( buffer ));
```

---

the above are the most obvious problems in the posted code.  If you had posted a cleanly compiles, short, example that can be run and still shows the problems, I could have helped you more.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to work on your suggestions and see if i either solve the problem or find a more concrete problem.